# Why my Extension Manager don't connect to the repository in typo3?

Tags: php, proxy, repository, xampp, typo3

Hi I want to learn typo3. For this I install the typo3 4.7 dummy & source on my xampp. I can start the backend but my Problem  is that I don't can use the Extension Manager.

I see the Extension Manager but if I want to change the language. I get the follow error:

```
router

tx_em_Repository_Utility: Could not access remote resource http://repositories.typo3.org/mirrors.xml.gz.
```

I search in google. and I read I must to set the ..

```
[curlUse] = 1
[curlProxyServer] = http://myProxy:port

[proxy_host] = myProxy
[proxy_port] = port
```

In my company we use a proxy and my curl is activ in my php.ini...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For typo3 Version 6.2 upwards use:

```
'HTML' => array(
            'proxy_host' => 'http://xx.xxx.xx.xx',
            'proxy_port' => 8080,
            'adapter' => 'curl',
    ),
```

in `typo3conf/LocalConfiguration.php`

Or set this via Install Tool (http://yourip/typo3/install/)

For all options look at the source:`typo3/sysext/core/Configuration/DefaultConfiguration.php`

This is deprecated but still **needed**, as I just found out (Language Update does not work without):

```
'SYS' => array(
   'curlUse' => 1,
   'curlProxyServer'  => 'http://xx.xxx.xx.xx:8080'
),
```

Answer (score -3):

It is nice thing that you are learning Typo3. It contains quality features, like an internal search engine, page editing and can run on many servers.I think that you need to install Typo3 6.0 version, because extension manager in Typo3 4.7 is criticized quite often for being unusable, slow and not able to do all the stuff you want to do with it while being able to do stuff you don’t want to do it.

for more information visit http://forge.typo3.org/projects/extensionmanager.